# Collection that uses ListIterator and is a unique list

Tags: java, list, collections, set, java-7

This has been annoying me in a project recently and my Google phoo is failing me at finding a suitable answer.

Is there a collection, that has access to the `ListIterator` but also only allows for unique values inside the collection?

Reasoning for this, I have a collection of items, that in this collection, there should only ever be one of each element. I also want to be able to traverse this collection in both directions whilst also being sorted or allow me to sort it using `Collections.Sort();`

I've not found anything suitable and had to write my own class using the following code:

```
public class UniqueArrayList<E> extends ArrayList<E> {
    @Override
    public boolean add(E element){
        if (this.contains(element))
            return false;
        else
            return super.add(element);
    }

    @Override
    public void add(int index, E element){
        if (this.contains(element))
            return;
        else
            super.add(index, element);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c){
        if (new HashSet<E>(c).size() < c.size())
            return false;
        for(E element : c){
            if (this.contains(c))
                return false;
        }
        return super.addAll(c);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(int index, Collection<? extends E> c) {
        if (new HashSet<E>(c).size() < c.size())
            return false;
        for(E element : c){
            if (this.contains(c))
                return false;
        }
        return super.addAll(index, c);
    }

    @Override
    public ListIterator<E> listIterator(int index) {
        if (index < 0 || index > this.size())
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index: "+index);
        return new ListItr(index);
    }

    @Override
    public ListIterator<E> listIterator() {
        return new ListItr(0);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        return new Itr();
    }

    private class Itr implements Iterator<E> {
        int cursor;       // index of next element to return
        int lastRet = -1; // index of last element returned; -1 if no such
        int expectedModCount = modCount;

        public boolean hasNext() {
            return cursor != size();
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public E next() {
            checkForComodification();
            int i = cursor;
            if (i >= size())
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            Object[] elementData = UniqueArrayList.this.toArray();
            if (i >= elementData.length)
                throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
            cursor = i + 1;
            return (E) elementData[lastRet = i];
        }

        public void remove() {
            if (lastRet < 0)
                throw new IllegalStateException();
            checkForComodification();

            try {
                UniqueArrayList.this.remove(lastRet);
                cursor = lastRet;
                lastRet = -1;
                expectedModCount = modCount;
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
                throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
            }
        }

        final void checkForComodification() {
            if (modCount != expectedModCount)
                throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        }


    }

    private class ListItr extends Itr implements ListIterator<E> {
        ListItr(int index) {
            super();
            cursor = index;
        }

        public boolean hasPrevious() {
            return cursor != 0;
        }

        public int nextIndex() {
            return cursor;
        }

        public int previousIndex() {
            return cursor - 1;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public E previous() {
            checkForComodification();
            int i = cursor - 1;
            if (i < 0)
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            Object[] elementData = UniqueArrayList.this.toArray();
            if (i >= elementData.length)
                throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
            cursor = i;
            return (E) elementData[lastRet = i];
        }

        public void set(E e) {
            if (lastRet < 0)
                throw new IllegalStateException();
            checkForComodification();
            try {
                //Need to allow this for the collections sort to work!
                //if (!UniqueArrayList.this.contains(e))
                UniqueArrayList.this.set(lastRet, e);
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
                throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
            }
        }

        public void add(E e) {
            checkForComodification();

            try {
                int i = cursor;
                UniqueArrayList.this.add(i, e);
                cursor = i + 1;
                lastRet = -1;
                expectedModCount = modCount;
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
                throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However this is far from perfect, for one I can't override the `ListIterator.set();` because `Collections.sort();` uses it to move items in the list. If I try to prevent non unique items from being added to the list here, the sort never happens.

So, does anyone have a better method or know of another collection that abides by the rules that I would like? Or do I just need to live with this rather irritating issue?

### [Edit]

This is the `Collections.sort();` method:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list) {
    Object[] a = list.toArray();
    Arrays.sort(a);
    ListIterator<T> i = list.listIterator();
    for (int j=0; j<a.length; j++) {
        i.next();
        i.set((T)a[j]);
    }
}
```

The reasoning they give for doing this is:

> This implementation dumps the specified list into an array, sorts the
>   array, and iterates over the list resetting each element from the
>   corresponding position in the array.  This avoids the n<sup>2</sup>
>   log(n) performance that would result from attempting to sort a linked
>   list in place.

Comment: Which Java version are you using?

Comment: Where did you come up with the idea that `Collections.sort();` uses `ListIterator.set();`?

Comment: Java 1.7 and check my updated text in the questions with regards to the sort method

Comment: Heh, interesting implementation. Too bad, in Java 8 you could've just overridden `List.sort()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Thor Stan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36646700/1441122) mentioned, a `TreeSet` gets you most of what you want. It ensures elements are unique, it keeps them sorted, and you can iterate it in either direction using `iterator()` or `descendingIterator()`.

It's not entirely clear why you're asking for `ListIterator` though. Most things about a `ListIterator` are very positional: the notion of an index, or adding something at the current position, or setting the current element. These don't make sense for a sorted set.

One aspect of a `ListIterator` that you might be looking for, though, is the ability to reverse directions in the midst of iteration. You can't do this directly with a `TreeSet` iterator, since it offers access only via an ordinary `Iterator` instead of a `ListIterator`.

However, a `TreeSet` implements the `NavigableSet` interface, which lets you step through the elements in order, in either direction. The `NavigableSet` interface is a subinterface of `SortedSet`, which provides the `first()` and `last()` methods to get you started at one of the "ends" of the set. Once you have an element in the set, you can step in either direction using the `lower(E)` and `higher(E)` methods. Or, if you want to start somewhere in the middle, you can't start at a position by index, but you can start with a value (which needn't be a member of the set) and then call `lower(E)` or `higher(E)`.

For example:

```
    TreeSet<String> set = new TreeSet<>(
        Arrays.asList("a", "z", "b", "y"));
    String cur;

    cur = set.first();     // a
    cur = set.higher(cur); // b
    cur = set.higher(cur); // y
    cur = set.higher(cur); // z
    cur = set.lower(cur);  // y
    cur = set.lower(cur);  // b
    cur = set.lower(cur);  // a
    cur = set.lower(cur);  // null
```

Comment: That's actually what I was looking for, those methods do what I wanted to do and allow iteration in either direction. I'll accept this one as the answer. Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 7):

When you need unique values you should try to switch to a Set.
You can use a TreeSet together with a Comparator instance to sort the entries. The descendingSet() method of TreeSet will give you the reverse order.
If you really need a ListIterator at some point you could create a temporary list from the set.

Comment: Does the `descendingSet()` know of the position and can then move forwards through the set, or would I need to relocate that position and start from there again if proceeding forward?

Comment: descendingSet() returns a Set, so there is no position.
descendingIterator() returns a new Iterator instance, so the position of any previous call is not known.

Comment: So it really is looking like the best bet is to do a TreeSet and then at the point of needing to move through the collection in either direction, I need to create a temporary list. Feels a bit of a shame there isn't some middle ground. I'll leave it open for another few days and if no one else has a better answer, I'll mark this as the answer

Answer (score 1):

Java considers `List` to allow non-unique items and `Set` to not. Sets obviously don't support `ListIterators` and therefore code that uses `ListIterator` can assume that the underlying collection is not a `Set`.

Java 8 doesn't use `ListIterator` for sorting anymore, but if you're stuck with Java 7 that doesn't really help you. Basically depending a lot on your context and usage, it might be useful to either use a `Set` like Thor Stan said in his response, creating a `List` on demand when needed.

Another option is to just provide your own `ListIterator` that accesses the list through a method that doesn't check for duplicates. This would have the advantage of not creating extraneous objects, but the `Set` option would most likely result in shorter code and is highly unlikely to be significant performance-wise.

There are probably other options too, but I can't think of any elegant ones.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with no easy answers.

The problem is that you have broken the contract for [`add(int, E)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-int-E-). This method must either add the element or throw an exception - it is not allowed to return without adding the element.

If you override [`set(int, E)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#set-E-) so that sometimes it doesn't set the element, it would break the contract for that method too, and it would prevent `Collections.sort()` from working as you identified.

I would not recommend breaking these contracts - it may cause other methods that act on lists to behave in unpredictable ways.

Others have experienced these difficulties - see the java docs for [SetUniqueList](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.2/org/apache/commons/collections/list/SetUniqueList.html) for example.

Another problem with your implementation is that it would be extremely slow because `ArrayList.contains()` is a linear search.

One solution would be to write a class that uses both an `ArrayList` and a `HashSet`, and write your own versions of `add` and `set`, rather than breaking the contracts for the usual versions. This is not tested, but you get the idea.

```
public final class MyList<E extends Comparable<? super E>> extends AbstractList<E> {

    private final List<E> list = new ArrayList<>();
    private final Set<E> set = new HashSet<>();

    public E get(int i) {
        return list.get(i);
    }

    public int size() {
        return list.size();
    } 

    public boolean tryAdd(E e) {
        return set.add(e) && list.add(e);
    }

    public boolean tryAdd(int i, E e) {
        if (set.add(e)) {
            list.add(i, e);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean trySet(int i, E e) {
        return set.add(e) && set.remove(list.set(i, e));
    }

    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        return set.remove(o) && list.remove(o);
    }

    public void sort() {
        Collections.sort(list);
    }

    // One bonus of this approach is that contains() is now O(1)
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        return set.contains(o);
    }

    // rest omitted.
}
```

Something like this would not break the contract for `List`. Note that with this version, `add` and `set` throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`, because this is the behaviour inherited from `AbstractList`. You would be able to `sort` by calling `myList.sort()`. Also, the `listIterator` method would work, but you would not be able to use it to `set` or `add` (although `remove` would work).

If you needed to `add` or `set` elements while iterating over this `List`, you would need to use an explicit index, rather than a `ListIterator`. Personally, I do not consider this a major problem. `ListIterator` is necessary for lists like `LinkedList` that do not have a constant time `get` method, but for `ArrayList` it's nice but not essential.

Comment: It was merely an internal class that shouldn't be used elsewhere, however as you said, it's a bad idea to break contract. I'm leaning more towards the `TreeSet` and then passing that to an `ArrayList` if I need to iterate it in both directions. However, thank you for the suggestion and advice. I'll make sure to keep an eye on contract fulfilling next time I try to override another class!